# Owncloud desktop client looses password on kwallet timeout

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, kwallet, owncloud-client

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma as a desktop environment.

After I login to a desktop sessio, the first thing that pops up is the password dialog of kwallet. One of the passwords it stores is that for a Nextcloud instance.

If I just login and then do not enter the kwalltet password for some time (a few minutes), the owncloud desktop client refuses to wait anymore and pops up a password dialog of its own. The problem is, that from that point there is no turning back to it using kwallet after it ha become opened. I cannot enter the nextcloud password (it's an app password) and if I cancel it it logs me out of my account and I have to tediously reconnect it.

Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1):

My work-around is to

1. explicitly close the NextCloud Desktop Client (from the Tray Icon bar)
2. continue with the login process to `kwallet` to successfully log in
3. (re-)start the NextCloud Desktop Client

At least this saves me from loosing my application specific password, which is a pain to reset each time.

For reference it's a known upstream issue:

- https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues/1011